# How to set up properly screenshots folder path for cypress-mochawesome-reporter?

Tags: mocha.js, cypress, mochawesome

My Mochawsome report created under installed cypress-mochawesome-reporter plugin doesn't contain screenshots as their path is wrong and contains not existing directory "screenshotscypress": "cypress/report/**screenshotscypress**/screenshots/". How to get rid of it? Screenshots for the failed tests are created properly and stored in "cypress/screenshots" folder by default. They are successfully copied to "report/screenshots" folder after test run is finished. But report itself contains only screenshot's icon but not the screenshot itself. Click on this icon displays the path mentioned above and containing "screenshotscypress" directory.